# Call a function of instance itself when it is initialized

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to React.js and I found one tricky thing that that stucks me.

I am trying to use one function of a class when I create an instance of that class, but it seems like I am not able to do this.

To be more specific:

I have a class called `PersonCalendar` and in this class, I have a function called `calculatedSalary` also, in this class, I have another attribute called `salary`.

Now I am trying to create an instance of this class by doing the following:

```
var personCal = new PersonCalender({salary: personCal.calculatedSalary(138)})
```

I also tried this:

```
var personCal = new PersonCalender({salary: this.calculatedSalary(138)})
```

Neither of them are working.

When I execute the code, the code will stop on this line saying that the function is undefined.

Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to deal with tricky situation?

Many thanks

Comment: In your first code sample, `personCal.calculatedSalary(138)` is undefined because the `personaCal` object doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Try `var personCal = new PersonCalender();` followed by `personCal.salary = personCal.calculatedSalary(138);`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with React. You simply cannot access something before it exists. Hence you cannot access the function of an instance before the instance exists.

I don't know what `PersonCalender` is doing or how you are processing its arguments, but it seems like you want to calculate the salary *inside* the constructor:

```
function PersonCalender(someNumber) {
    this.salary = this.calculatedSalary(someNumber);
}
```

Or make `calculatedSalary` static if it does need access to the instance:

```
PersonCalender.calculatedSalary = function(...) { ...};

var personCal = new PersonCalender({salary: PersonCalender.calculatedSalary(138)})
```

I recommend to read the [MDN article about OOP in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) to make yourself more familiar with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 lines are wrong for 2 different reasons:

1. `var personCal = new PersonCalender({salary: personCal.calculatedSalary(138)})` wouldn't work since `personCal` is `undefined` at this time. Only after the line has executed will it have any value
2. `var personCal = new PersonCalender({salary: this.calculatedSalary(138)})` would probably not work since `this` is not a `PersonCalendar`, and doesn't have a `calculatedSalary` method.

You should probably change your constructor to receive an argument an set `salary` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `PersonCalendar` is a React component: you should pass the salary to your React component and do the calculation internally:

```
var personCal = new PersonCalender({salary: 138});

var PersonCalendar = React.createClass({
   componentDidMount: function() {
      this.setState({ 
         computedSalary: this.calculatedSalary(this.props.salary) 
      });
   },
   render: function() {
     ... use this.state.computedSalary
   }
});
```

Others have already pointed out that you can't access properties on a nonexistent object.